# Do I need a filter to use my Canon EOS 60Da for daylight photography?

Tags: canon, filters, canon-60d, infrared

Which filter do I need for the 60Da to use it in normal daytime use?
Apparently I need a IR filter.

Could someone please explain exactly which one I need and perhaps a link to a place I can buy one? Thanks! (I'm very new to this)

Comment: Also see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/912/is-it-possible-to-do-infrared-photography-with-digital-cameras

Comment: I would recommend seriously questioning anyone who says that you *need* anything for photography beyond a camera and a lens. Why do you need it? What is it for? What happens if you don't have it, etc.

Comment: Have you tried it as-is?  Might only need to tweak the white balance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the 60Da's modification to increase IR sensitivity for astrophotography, if you plan on using the camera for regular visible-light photography, you probably should get an **IR cut filter**, otherwise you may experience color shifts when the sensor gathers both visible and non-visible light together (magenta cast with synthetic fabrics, and foliage greens being off are common issues with full-spectrum cameras used without a UV/IR cut filter).

You don't want to get what most people think of as an IR filter (like the Hoya R72). That is an IR-*pass* filter which blocks visible light and only lets IR through--you're trying to do the opposite: block the IR/UV light.  Most IR cut filters will also cut UV,  because some cameras don't have IR/UV filters over the sensor (e.g., the Leica M8).

Since UV/IR cut filters aren't cheap, you can get one filter that's the largest size you'll need and then "adapt" it to your other lenses with step-up rings.  What size you'll need depends on the lenses you'll be using.

Comment: Fantastic information thank you. For anyone reading the standard lense size of the 60Da is 72mm. I may purchase this one: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/857390-REG/Hoya_A72UVIR_72_mm_UV_and.html

Comment: That would depend on what lens you have...

Comment: There is no "standard filter size" for the camera body; 72mm may be too small depending on the lenses you're planning to use. Many of Canon's L lenses use a 77mm filter. Think about future lens purchases, too.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're getting confused between a feature of the camera and something you can modify - your camera has the feature you need. See this: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/canon/announcements/canon-eos-60da-takes-a-astrophotography

You probably don't need an IR (infrared) filter (take some shots first and find out, be sure to try it at night and day). The only difference between the "A" and other cameras is the A is sensitive to one specific frequency of IR which is commonly emitted by astronomical objects, allowing your camera to be more sensitive to those objects. This is useful for photographs of nebulas and other 'diffuse' phenomena. Regular terrestrial objects emit this wavelength too, and when trying to take "normal" photos in the visible spectrum, you may get some "bleed" from the IR emissions, causing the photo to look unnatural because it will capture light we normally can't see. You can block that light with a filter, but it's going to be a lense filter, for every lense where you need to use it.

These products are easily found with a Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=IR+cut+filter (look on the right side)

Some people recommend using UV (ultraviolet) filters for beginners to protect lenses while they get used to carrying lenses around, but the value of that practice is debatable. You don't need filters, you don't need tripods, you need GOOGLE.

Go to Google and start typing in things like this...

https://www.google.com/search?q=learning+photography

https://www.google.com/search?q=photography+tips+for+beginners

Read articles on Google for at least a week, then come back here. You're asking incredibly basic questions and we can't really answer them without writing books, which have already been written. Take the time to read them. Most of the advice you need is free on this site and others.

Show us that you are going to make an effort to become a good photographer and we will take an interest in helping you. That's kind of a rule on this site. We will help you, but we won't do it for you.

You have an excellent camera. You can learn 90% of photography without buying anything else. Whoever is pushing you to buy stuff, please stop listening to them. If it's you, cut it out :)

Comment: I think you've missed the point that the EOS 60Da is especially designed for astrophotography which means its been modded and Canon has officially stated that it needs a particular IR filter for normal daytime use. I want advice on which filter, what is called and where I can buy it

Comment: Ah, what a difference one character makes. I'll stand by the general tone of my comment though. I'll edit the question with the 60D*a* in mind.